# Does excel if function can't return column if text long is long?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have an excel if formula

```
=IF(A2 = Table1[Action], Table1[Description],"")
```

It works for rows when Table1[Description] column is small but returns #VALUE! if *Description* column text is larger than 255 characters. So I am thinking the problem is with text in *Description* column being too long?

How can I come across this and return the large text? The match criteria is simple and short column. Thanks.

[image: excel spreadsheetsheet]

As can be seen, the formula returns two values that matches Index = 1 but first one is #VALUE! and 2nd was is correct.

As can be seen below, it does work if the I reduce text string in B2 to a short one.

[image]

I am following this tutorial https://youtu.be/Ssm0bb6VWuY?t=318

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem by creating column text > 255 characters. You will need to add more detail

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I was able to reproduce it in a simple sheet and added screenshot.

Comment: @zar i just checked it does work, can you let us know what is the excel version you are using ?

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya Excel 365

Comment: Still unable to reproduce.  Perhaps upload an xlsx workbook demonstrating the problem, and post a link here.

Comment: In Excel 365 you could use the `FILTER` function.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld Sir has already informed you, you need to use `FILTER()` function no need to use an `IF()` function.

Comment: So you could do this : `=TEXTJOIN(",",1,FILTER(Table1[Description],Table1[Action]=E2,"None"))`

Comment: @MayukhBhattacharya thanks that produces correct results (with Filter)

Comment: @zar you can post your answer and accept to close it.